# How to uninstall .NET Core 2.1.4 from CentOS?

Tags: .net-core

I installed .NET Core  2.1.4  on my CentOS from [Microsoft .NET Core Installation Site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/centos). I want to uninstall it. I could not find any steps online. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse all the steps you followed from the [Microsoft .NET Core Installation](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/centos) Site:

```
sudo yum remove dotnet-sdk-2.1.103
sudo yum remove libunwind libicu
```

If you also want to remove the rpm repository:

```
sudo yum remove /etc/yum.repos.d/dotnetdev.repo
```

To remove the imported gpg-key do the following:

1. Get a list of imported keys

   ```
   rpm -qa gpg-pubkey \* --qf "%{version}-%{release} %{summary}\n"
   ```
2. There are a lot of entries, look for Microsoft (Release signing), copy the key and then issue the following command (paste the key after gpg-pubkey-):

   ```
   sudo rpm -e --allmatches gpg-pubkey-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer should be worked,but I need one more step to make it ok when I reinstalled it ;The step is :1 echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet' > /etc/profile.d/dotnetdev.sh; 2 source /etc/profile.d/dotnetdev.sh